# Android BroadcastReceiver is not receiving anything (SMS)

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I know many people have the same problem, I read a lot on stackoverflow, but for me still BroadcastReceivers to not receive SMS...

Manifest:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.msit_hosting.bos_lage_fms"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="0.0.1b" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        
        <receiver android:name="de.msit_hosting.bos_lage_fms.SMSReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
        
        <activity
            android:name=".FMSActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="de.msit_hosting.bos_lage_fms.FMSActivity" />
        </activity>
        
        <service
        android:name=".PositionSendService"
        android:label="Position send Service" >
     </service>
     
        <receiver android:name="de.msit_hosting.bos_lage_fms.SMSReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="2000">
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Receiver:

```html
package de.msit_hosting.bos_lage_fms;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Log.e("SMS", "Receiver fired...");
  
  /*
  Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
  
  if(data != null) {
   Object[] sms_data = (Object[])data.get("pdus");
   
   for(int i = 0; i < sms_data.length; i++) {
    SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])sms_data[i]);
    
    String src = msg.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
    String body = msg.getMessageBody();
   
    if(src != null && body != null) {
     Log.i("SMS", src + ": " + body);
    }
   }
  }
  */
 }
 
}
```

I commented out everything except the Log-message for testing reasons - but even this is not called. I tried lower priorities and other things recommended here and in other forums, but nothing works.

For me it's special, that it's not Handcent or something like this which blocks the message, since even on the Android Emulator no Log message is shown...

Can you please help?

thank you

Merlin

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the following changes:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" >
 <intent-filter android:priority="999">
  <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also depending on your operational system version, you might need to install the app, run it once, and then you may see the results.
If any of those changes fixed your problem, those may be:

Wrong class targetting. You appear to append twice the package name.

Wrong priority, the google docs state that developers should use integer values between -999 and 999

Wrong version startup. I do believe it was version 3.1 where broacastreceivers need an activity in order for them to register properly.